# getComputedStyle just returns null

Tags: javascript, css

In Javascript I need to get the css style of an element, based on the search I did I used the getComputedStyle, although my element has background-color(I'm trying to get this background-color) doing the console.log for status shows null.

```js
var element = document.querySelector('#word')
var style = getComputedStyle(element)
var status = style.color
console.log(status)
```

```html
<div id="word">Word</div>
```

Comment: the main issue is that `style.color` isn't the background colour - you'll want `style.backgroundColor` if you want the background colour (note the camel-case instead of kebab-case ... you could use `style['background-color']` as well

Comment: OK, so you want backgroundColor rather than color but regardless I am suspicious that you are getting 'null' since there will normally be a default setting for color (rgb(0, 0, 0) on my Edge/Chrome and probably many other browsers). Are you certain that you have loaded the element with id 'word' before you start to run the JS, and that that null came from getComputedStyle? Could you make your code into a snippet we can run which shows the problem?

Comment: I changed your code to an executable snippet, it doesn't reproduce the problem you describe. Please update it to match your application.